# What are each of the subfolders of the .gradle folder for?

Tags: gradle, directory, directory-structure

I was quite surprised that I couldn't find this anywhere, but anyways, I would like to know the purpose of each folder in the `.gradle` folder, and how safe it is to delete them, especially in terms of portability.

- I know that I need the `caches` folder, since it contains the
  downloaded dependencies.
- The `daemon` folder seems to only contain
  logs?
- `workers` is apparently empty for me
- `wrapper` seems irrelevant, since I don't use gradle wrapper. Why does it even download all those wrappers?
- No idea about `native`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory layout is described in ["The Directories and Files Gradle Uses"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home) chapter of its user guide.

```
├── caches                   // <1>
│   ├── 4.8                  // <2>
│   ├── 4.9                  // <2>
│   ├── ⋮
│   ├── jars-3               // <3>
│   └── modules-2            // <3>
├── daemon                   // <4>
│   ├── ⋮
│   ├── 4.8
│   └── 4.9
├── init.d                   // <5>
│   └── my-setup.gradle
├── wrapper
│   └── dists                // <6>
│       ├── ⋮
│       ├── gradle-4.8-bin
│       ├── gradle-4.9-all
│       └── gradle-4.9-bin
└── gradle.properties        // <7>
```

1. Global cache directory (for everything that's not project-specific)
2. Version-specific caches (e.g. to support incremental builds)
3. Shared caches (e.g. for artifacts of dependencies)
4. Registry and logs of the [Gradle Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#gradle_daemon)
5. Global [initialization scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#init_scripts)
6. Distributions downloaded by the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#gradle_wrapper)
7. Global [Gradle configuration properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

From version 4.10 onwards, Gradle automatically cleans its user home directory. The cleanup runs in the background when the Gradle daemon is stopped or shuts down. If using `--no-daemon`, it runs in the foreground after the build session with a visual progress indicator.

The following cleanup strategies are applied periodically (at most every 24 hours):

- Version-specific caches in `caches/<gradle-version>/` are checked for whether they are still in use. If not, directories for release versions are deleted after 30 days of inactivity, snapshot versions after 7 days of inactivity.
- Shared caches in `caches/` (e.g. `jars-*`) are checked for whether they are still in use. If there's no Gradle version that still uses them, they are deleted.
- Files in shared caches used by the current Gradle version in `caches/` (e.g. `jars-3` or `modules-2`) are checked for when they were last accessed. Depending on whether the file can be recreated locally or would have to be downloaded from a remote repository again, it will be deleted after 7 or 30 days of not being accessed, respectively.
- Gradle distributions in `wrapper/dists/` are checked for whether they are still in use, i.e. whether there's a corresponding version-specific cache directory. Unused distributions are deleted.

`native` seem to contain [platform-specific dependencies](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/native/native.gradle#L4) (like `.so`, `.dll`) for libraries like Jansi: it needs them to provide rich console output (like colours in the output). The code for that features is not documented, but you can take a look [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/native). Particularly [`library.jansi.path` system property](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/native/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/nativeintegration/jansi/JansiBootPathConfigurer.java#L28) [points](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/native/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/nativeintegration/jansi/JansiBootPathConfigurer.java#L56) to `~/.gradle/native/jansi/1.17.1/linux64` (on my machine; you can check that by printing `System.getProperties()` in a custom Gradle task).

`workers` [seems to be used as a working directory](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7323) for the workers described in [Workers API](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/).

`wrappers` could be downloaded by the IDE. Basically, if you have this directory non-empty that means that you've actually used a wrapper at least once.